# Guardar un fichero.txt con FileChooser

Tags: java, java-swing, backend, java-awt

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que es crear una ventana gráfica con un `JTextArea` con un `JMenu` y en ese menu tiene diferentes pestañas, y en la opción de "*guardar como*" quiero que me guarde el texto de ese `JTextArea` en un *archivo.txt*, el problema es que me crea el archivo pero no me guarda el texto. He probado a hacer el método sin `BufferedWriter` pero me seguía sin guardar el texto en el *fichero.txt* y ya no se qué se me puede estar escapando, os comparto el código que llevo hecho hasta ahora y algunas capturas de pantalla de como se ve el programa y el resultado que me sale cuando se guarda.

-Código del programa

```
public class VentanaGrafica extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// atributos
private JMenuBar barra;
private JFrame ventana;
private JTextArea areaTexto;
private JMenuItem opcionNuevo;
private JMenuItem opcionAbrir;
private JMenuItem opcionGuardar;
private JMenuItem opcionGuardarComo;
private JMenuItem opcionSalir;
private JMenuItem opcionCortar;
private JMenuItem opcionPegar;
private JMenuItem opcionCopiar;
private JMenuItem opcionAjusteLinea;
private JMenuItem opcionFuente;
private File archivo;
private BufferedWriter bw;

public VentanaGrafica() {

    barra = new JMenuBar();
}

public void Ejecuta() {

    // creo la ventana

    ventana = new JFrame("bloc de notas");
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setLocation(400, 150);
    ventana.setSize(400, 420);
    ventana.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ventana.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    // creo el panel del menu

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    // pongo fondo al panel
    panel1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    // creo los componentes del menu

    JMenu Archivo = new JMenu("Archivo");
    JMenu Editar = new JMenu("Editar");
    JMenu Formato = new JMenu("Formato");

    // añado los componentes a la barra de menu

    barra.add(Archivo);
    barra.add(Editar);
    barra.add(Formato);

    // añado los componentes de Archivo

    opcionNuevo = new JMenuItem("Nuevo");
    Archivo.add(opcionNuevo);
    opcionAbrir = new JMenuItem("Abrir");
    Archivo.add(opcionAbrir);
    Archivo.add(new JSeparator());
    opcionGuardar = new JMenuItem("Guardar");
    Archivo.add(opcionGuardar);
    opcionGuardarComo = new JMenuItem("Guardar como...");
    Archivo.add(opcionGuardarComo);
    Archivo.add(new JSeparator());
    opcionSalir = new JMenuItem("Salir");
    Archivo.add(opcionSalir);

    // añado los componentes de Editar

    opcionCortar = new JMenuItem("Cortar");
    Editar.add(opcionCortar);
    opcionPegar = new JMenuItem("Pegar");
    Editar.add(opcionPegar);
    opcionCopiar = new JMenuItem("Copiar");
    Editar.add(opcionCopiar);

    // añado los componentes de Formato
    opcionAjusteLinea = new JMenuItem("Ajuste de línea");
    Formato.add(opcionAjusteLinea);
    opcionFuente = new JMenuItem("Fuente...");
    Formato.add(opcionFuente);

    // configuro mi textarea

    areaTexto = new JTextArea(20, 30);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(areaTexto);

    // añado los componentes al panel

    panel1.add(barra);
    panel1.add(scroll);

    // añado eventos a los compontenes del menu

    opcionAbrir.addActionListener(this);
    opcionGuardarComo.addActionListener(this);

    // añado el panel a la ventana
    ventana.add(panel1);

    ventana.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
if (event.getSource() == opcionGuardarComo) {

        JFileChooser guardarArchivo = new JFileChooser();
        guardarArchivo.setDialogTitle("Guardar como");

        guardarArchivo.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int returnVal2 = guardarArchivo.showSaveDialog(guardarArchivo);

        if (returnVal2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            archivo = guardarArchivo.getSelectedFile();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo se ha guardado correctamente");

            try {

                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
                bw.write(this.areaTexto.getText());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        else if (returnVal2 == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has cancelado la operacion");
        }

    }

  }
}
```

-- Imágenes de la ventana gráfica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alli lo que pasa con `BufferedWriter` es que necesitas llamar a `flush()` o aun mejor a `close()` para cerrar el flujo y así ya podrá dejar persistencia de datos en el archivo.

Siendo así, tienes dos opciones, la primera no muy distinta (*si acaso*) de la que tienes planteada:

```
try {
  bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
  bw.write(areaTexto.getText());
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    if(bw!=null)
      bw.close();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

O en la otra mano tienes una forma mas limpia y legible vía *try* con recursos:

```
try (BufferedWriter BW=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo))) {
  BW.write(areaTexto.getText());
} catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

La ventaja de usar ésta ultima solución es que uno se despreocupa de cerrar el *stream* de manera explícita ya que esa labor sucede de manera automática tras bambalinas.

Comment: Gracias ya me funciona, era esa tonteria al final, añadí el bw.close() y ya me copio todo el texto del JTextArea en el fichero.